# Is __init__ a class method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I was looking into Python's super method and multiple inheritance. I read along something like when we use super to call a base method which has implementation in all base classes, only one class' method will be called even with variety of arguments. For example,

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print "In Base 1"

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "In Base 2"

class Child(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__('Intended for base 1')
        super(Child, self).__init__()# Intended for base 2
```

This produces `TyepError` for the first `super` method. `super` would call whichever method implementation it first recognizes and gives `TypeError` instead of checking for other classes down the road. However, this will be much more clear and work fine when we do the following:

```
class Child(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        Base1.__init__(self, 'Intended for base 1')
        Base2.__init__(self) # Intended for base 2
```

This leads to two questions:

1. Is `__init__` method a static method or a class method?
2. Why use super, which implicitly choose the method on it's own rather than explicit call to the method like the latter example? It looks lot more cleaner than using super to me. So what is the advantage of using `super` over the second way(other than writing the base class name with the method call)

Comment: Its a class method (aka instance method if I understand you correctly). Static dont have self as the first argument. Super is in general better, as you dont need to known name of the base class.

Comment: But if we are going to use the base class method, it would be preferable to know which class method we are calling, in terms of multiple inheritance right?

Comment: There's no way the second code can work fine. Plus that's not how `super()` works, calling super twice doesn't mean it will call the next class in the MRO automatically.

Comment: this would be a special case. but for multiple inheritance when constructors dont take arguments, super calls base classes constructors from [left to right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: Thanks @AshwiniChaudhary... Updated the question for the second code

Comment: And I mean that by calling super with different number of arguments, it throws a `TypeError` rather than trying to check whether any other method can fit the bill. So why go through super at all?

Comment: You have mis-understood how `super` works, `super()` simply checks for the given method in the MRO chain, here it is going to be `Base1.__init__`, now it's up to `Base1.__init__`'s whether the next `__init__` can be called or not, if there's a `super()` call present, then it will look for `__init__` in classes that appear after `Base1` in Child's MRO, and that is `Base2` here.  Read: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`super()` in the face of multiple inheritance, especially on methods that are present on `object` [can get a bit tricky](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).  The general rule is that if you use `super`, then *every class in the hierarchy* should use `super`.  A good way to handle this for `__init__` is to make every method take `**kwargs`, and always use keyword arguments everywhere.  By the time the call to `object.__init__` occurs, all arguments should have been popped out!

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        print "In Base 1", a
        super(Base1, self).__init__()

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print "In Base 2"
        super(Base2, self).__init__()

class Child(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(a="Something for Base1")
```

See the linked article for way more explanation of how this works and how to make it work for you!

Edit: At the risk of answering two questions, "Why use super at all?"

We have `super()` for many of the same reasons we have classes and inheritance, as a tool for modularizing and abstracting our code.  When operating on an instance of a class, you don't need to know all of the gritty details of how that class was implemented, you only need to know about its methods and attributes, and how you're meant to use that public interface for the class.  In particular, you can be confident that changes in the implementation of a class can't cause you problems as a user of its instances.

The same argument holds when deriving new types from base classes.  You don't want or need to worry about how those base classes were implemented.  Here's a concrete example of how not using super might go wrong.  suppose you've got:

```
class Foo(object):
     def frob(self):
         print "frobbign as a foo"
class Bar(object):
     def frob(self):
         print "frobbign as a bar"
```

and you make a subclass:

```
class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
    def frob(self):
        Foo.frob(self)
        Bar.frob(self)
```

Everything's fine, but then you realize that when you get down to it, 
`Foo` really is a kind of `Bar`, so you change it

```
 class Foo(Bar):
     def frob(self):
         print "frobbign as a foo"
         Bar.frob(self)
```

Which is all fine, except that in your derived class, `FooBar.frob()` calls `Bar.frob()` *twice*.

This is the exact problem `super()` solves, it protects you from calling superclass implementations more than once (when used as directed...)

Answer (score 11):

As for your first question, `__init__` is neither a staticmethod nor a classmethod; it is an ordinary instance method.  (That is, it receives the instance as its first argument.)

As for your second question, if you want to explicitly call multiple base class implementations, then doing it explicitly as you did is indeed the only way.  However, you seem to be misunderstanding how `super` works.  When you call `super`, it does not "know" if you have already called it.  Both of your calls to `super(Child, self).__init__` call the Base1 implementation, because that is the "nearest parent" (the most immediate superclass of `Child`).

You would use `super` if you want to call *just* this immediate superclass implementation.  You would do this if that superclass was also set up to call its superclass, and so on.  The way to use `super` is to have each class call only the next implementation "up" in the class hierarchy, so that the sequence of `super` calls overall calls everything that needs to be called, in the right order.  This type of setup is often called "cooperative inheritance", and you can find various articles about it online, including [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127) and [here](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: But in my example, we can see that `__init__` can be called even without creating an instance. `Base2.__init__()`. Here, we are not creating an instance of `Base2` class right?

Comment: @thiruvenkadam: an instance of `Child` (ie, `self` in `Child.__init__(self)`) *is* an instance of `Base2`!  That's what it means to be a sub-class.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam: That code doesn't actually work (as you seem to have noticed since you edited it).

Comment: @IfLoop Thanks... I missed that out :-)

Comment: @BrenBarn yes... Another user pointed out the flaw with the second code. Fixed the second and added a few more explanation as to what I am looking for in the question.