# Super with arguments in case of multiple inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, parameters, multiple-inheritance, super

I have a class that inherits from two other classes whose `__init__` take both a parameter like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(C, self).__init__(a, b)

c = ClassC(1, 2)
```

This gives a `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`.

When setting `b` in `B` to a fixed value and passing only 1 parameter to `super` then trying to access `b` in `C` gives an `AttributeError: 'ClassC' object has no attribute 'b'`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = 2

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(C, self).__init__(a)

        print self.a
        print self.b

c = ClassC(1, 2)
```

When calling the `__init__` manually everything seems to be fine:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        A.__init__(a)
        B.__init__(b)

        print self.a
        print self.b

c = ClassC(1, 2)
```

So how can I get this inheritance straight and how can I manage the parameters for `__init__` of inherited classes when using `super`? Is it even possible? How does `super` know which parameters are to pass to which class?

Comment: You need super calls in other classes as well: [Python's super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: Related: [Is `__init__` a class method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28577378/846892)

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206015/pythons-multiple-inheritance-picking-which-super-to-call